# Duplicate SQL records to the same table with manually auto increment id

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to write a query which will return those records:

```
select * 
from [CloneConfiguration] 
where InstrumentId = 2
```

[image]

and insert them into the same table with changing the following columns:

1. `Id` - the new record will need a unique `id` number (because it is the primary key without that it defined as auto increment)
2. `Instrument id` - change the instrument id to another number (3 for example)

I tried the following query which doesn't work.

```
INSERT INTO [CloneConfiguration] 
   SELECT 
       MAX(Id) + 1, 3,
       [SourceCCy1Id], [SourceCCy2Id], [SourceProviderId], 
       [TargetCCy1Id], [TargetCCy2Id], [TargetProviderId], [Remark]
   FROM 
       [CloneConfiguration] 
   WHERE 
       InstrumentId =2
```

Error:

> Column 'CloneConfiguration.SourceCCy1Id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: If you are using `max` functin, you need a `group by` clause

Comment: Add the tag for your dbms please

Comment: Added `sql-server` and `tsql` tags based on the non-standard square brackets being used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do what you want in a single query by doing:

```
INSERT INTO [CloneConfiguration] 
    SELECT COALESCE(m.maxid + 1, 1), 3, [SourceCCy1Id], [SourceCCy2Id],
           [SourceProviderId], [TargetCCy1Id], [TargetCCy2Id], 
           [TargetProviderId], [Remark]
    FROM [CloneConfiguration] CROSS JOIN
         (SELECT max(id) as maxid FROM CloneConfiguration) m
    WHERE InstrumentId = 2 ;
```

If you are inserting *multiple rows*, then use `row_number()` as well:

```
INSERT INTO [CloneConfiguration] 
    SELECT COALESCE(m.maxid, 0) + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)),
           3, [SourceCCy1Id], [SourceCCy2Id],
           [SourceProviderId], [TargetCCy1Id], [TargetCCy2Id], 
           [TargetProviderId], [Remark]
    FROM [CloneConfiguration] CROSS JOIN
         (SELECT max(id) as maxid FROM CloneConfiguration) m
    WHERE InstrumentId = 2 ;
```

That said, the correct solution is to define the id to be an `identity` column.  Then the database takes care of assigning a unique id.  Your queries also will not have race conditions.  So, the above work if there is only one user, but can fail if there are multiple users.

Answer (score 1):

This is assuming sql-server, but I guess you get the point anyway:

```
DECLARE @MAXID INT = (SELECT MAX(Id) FROM [CloneConfiguration]) -- You probably want to number from the highest Id regardless of InstrumentId

INSERT INTO [CloneConfiguration] 
SELECT @MAXID + ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Id)
,      3
,      [SourceCCy1Id]
,      [SourceCCy2Id]
,      [SourceProviderId]
,      [TargetCCy1Id]
,      [TargetCCy2Id]   
,      [TargetProviderId]
,      [Remark]
FROM   [CloneConfiguration] 
WHERE  InstrumentId=2
```

The idea is to first get the MAX(Id) currently in the table, and add a `ROW_NUMBER` based on the selected Id's.

By the way, it's also a good idea to name the columns you want to insert into:

```
INSERT INTO [CloneConfiguration] (Id, InstrumentId...)
...
```

Comment: `@MAXID+1` should do..why do you need `row_number`?

Comment: @vkp, If `@MAXID` = 33, all selected records will end up with 34 (I assume more than 1 record can be selected, as OP's sample shows...), which is still not unique